# command substitution in docker CMD

Tags: python, docker, cmd, dockerfile, command-substitution

Using:

```
CMD ["$(pipenv --venv)/bin/python3", "main.py", "/root/uploads"]
```

Causes an error on `docker run`:

```
Error response from daemon: invalid header field value "oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"$(pipenv --venv)/bin/python3\\\": stat $(pipenv --venv)/bin/python3: no such file or directory\"\n"
```

Is there any way to make evaluate command substitutions like `$(pipenv --venv)/bin/python3` in the CMD section?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change it to below

```
CMD ["bash", "-c", "$(pipenv --venv)/bin/python3 main.py /root/uploads"]
```

If that still gives you issue, change `$` to `$$`